# click target area overlapping over targets

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have 4 simple img and h4 which are targeted to 3rd party links.  The class `projectImage2` overlaps the other 3 and much of the page is targeted to the click

```
<a href="https://eliottenos.github.io/eliott-game/"<div class="game"<h4>Game Application</h4></div></a>

<a href="https://github.com/eliottenos/filebucket-client"><img class="projectImage2"src="http://i.imgur.com/iiGiuX7.png" 
title="FileBucket Application" /></a>

<a href="https://eliottenos.github.io/filebucket-client/"><div 
   class="fileBucket"><h4>FileBucket Application</h4></div></a>

   <a href="https://github.com/eliottenos/eliott-game"><img 
   class="projectImage1"src="http://i.imgur.com/iiGiuX7.png" title="Game 
   Application" /></a>
```

The only thing I can that think that could be throwing it off is the CSS?

```
.game {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 250px;
  padding-right: 250px;
  padding-top: 130px;
}

.fileBucket {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 250px;
  padding-right: 250px;
  padding-top: 200px;
}

.projectImage2 {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  top: 450px;
  left: 440px;
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
}

.projectImage1 {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  top: 380px;
  left: 440px;
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Sorry i don't understand the question without seeing what you mean, can you replicate the problem or create a demo with codepen or similar?

Comment: Ok i can tell you that the problem is definitely with postion: absolute, but we can't see the whole picture, or why you need position: absolute.

Comment: @Mindless so I've made a codepen which doesn't seem to be displaying correctly but you'll get the idea of why I'm using absolute -> https://codepen.io/eliottenos/pen/MvmwZw  To get a better understanding of the display it is deployed to eliottenos.com

Comment: or this repo might be a better reference https://github.com/eliottenos/portfolio-frontend

Comment: hehe, i see what you mean from your website, you don't need position absolute, your html is all over the place, i will quickly make the changes to the problem you have, maybe you should try something like bootstrap as a template first before creating your own.

Comment: Thanks, good tip, still pretty new to the game!

Answer (score 0):

So i had a proper look, the problem is not only the links but how your html is structured, there's position:absolute on pretty much everything, so everything is overlapping everything, i would strongly suggest you to use bootstrap template as a start, you can easily set columns and rows with bootstrap and it will be responsive. i tried to put the links in the correct position, but because you have position:absolute on everything, i would have to change how the html is laid out, for example some of the things which is below another part in html pops up on top of that content.

You have to think your html as horizontal rows, doesn't matter if they are left or right, if they appear on the same line, put it under one div.

For example, for your content with bootstrap, you could do something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
      Contact Details, Phone Number etc...
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
      <p>
      Fullstack Web Developer coming from a diverse, technical business background. Having worked and traveled the world, I have acquired a breadth of skill sets through different industries which has culminated in my goal of becoming a trained fullstack web developer.
     </p>
     <ul class="main">
        <li>Write HTML, CSS, and JavaScript for displays in contemporary browsers with responsive design practices</li>
        <li>Develop back-end web applications and APIs using a modern programming languages and MVC web development framework</li>
        <li>Collaborate with teams using an agile development workflow and widely-accepted collaboration practices using Git and GitHub for version control</li>
        <li>Improve and demonstrate web development skill-set by building a series of full-stack web applications</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where the left side takes up 4 columns and right side takes 8 columns and the total column width always adds up to 12. So you can do something like this as well.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>
```